# Ubuntu 20.04 does not find certain wifi networks

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I have a very odd problem since I updated my Lenovo T430 from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. The computer does not find certain wifi networks. In general wifi is working as I am typing these lines being hooked up to a wifi hotspot provided by my smartphone. However, the wifi network in the flat I am sitting in does not show up on the available networks. Prior to the update, I was able to use this wifi network.

Has anybody suggestions for trouble-shooting this?

Most results I find deal with wifi that is not working entirely, which is not the case in my case.

---

I have already tried to delete the network, and re-enter its SSID. It still does not show up. It works, since there is an iPad around which is connected to it.

Comment: Your wi-fi may be running on a channel that your wi-fi card doesn't support. Do `iwlist freq` and compare that to the channel settings for the wi-fi network.

Comment: Two weeks ago, I was running Ubuntu 18.04 on that very hardware and the network worked. There was nothing changed with the settings of the router.

Comment: If the router is set to "auto" for the channel setting, it may have just switched to an unsupported (by your wi-fi card) channel. Do as my previous comments says. You can also use `iwlist scan`.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; iw reg get; lsusb`